# How do you delete a URL link in a batch file?

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to delete 2 links from my desktop which keep getting added by my company.

This is my batch file:

```
del "%userprofile%\Desktop\Item1.lnk" /Q
del "%userprofile%\Desktop\Item2.lnk" /Q
```

Item1 deletes fine with this batch file but Item 2 does not. Item1 links to an exe file, Item2 is a URL. I have tried changing it to the following:

Item2.url
Item2.???

Anyone able to help please?

Comment: To me this is more a question for superuser, it is about the execution of a single command. What error message is generated when you try to delete the file?

Comment: Could Not Find C:\Users\<my_username>\Desktop\Item2.lnk

Comment: Not only is this off topic here, but there is no reason for the `/Q` on either of those two lines. Also, if both files were really on the user desktop, you could have used the `/Q` but named both files in just one `del` command. My best guess for your actual issue is that you should change line two to ```Del "%Public%\Desktop\Item2.lnk" /A /F```, _(although I suspect you'll receive a permission error)_.

Comment: Why is this off topic? Where should I be posting this? I copied the /Q from another thread on stack overflow (I understand a little bit of scripting but I'm not a programmer).   I tried what you suggested and it displays the same error of "Could not Find..." that I listed above.

Comment: Because there is not an issue with your code. Your issue is one, or a combination of, invalid file extension, invalid file basename, or invalid file location. Programmers are not in a position to correct the part that only you can ascertain. How about you at least check the contents of the desktop, by opening a Command Prompt window, typing ```Dir "%UserProfile%\Desktop" /A /O:N /X```, then pressing `[ENTER]`.

Comment: Thank you for the help. The link I am trying to delete is not showing up when I use your dir command, which explains why my batch file is not deleting it. I will have to work out why it is 'invisible'.

Comment: It is not invisible! The command I gave you should show every file, including hidden ones! The file, as I've already mentioned, in not in the location you are looking for it at.

Comment: Well, I wish I could send a screenshot, because there is a link on my desktop, and it's not showing up in the list when I do the directory command you gave me.

Answer (score 0):

On your desktop, find the entry you want to delete.
Right-click on this entry and go to 'Properties'.
In 'Properties' switch to tab 'General'.
There you will find the exact filename and the filetype (extension).
Shortcut(lnk) and Internet Shortcut(url) are different filetypes and have different extensions.
Combine the filename with the extension to get the filename you need in your script.
Also check the location of the file in the tab 'General'.
You need the correct file path and filename including extension in your script.